# AxWindowsMediaPlayer Clip Will Sometimes Not Play

Tags: c#, .net, windows, media-player

I have a simple one-threaded windows forms .NET 4.5 app where user listens to spoken words (wav files) and then selects the correct picture that represents the word.

The problem is that the clip will sometimes (very rarely - about 1% of the time and completelly at random) not play...

This is the method for playing clips:

```
    public static void PlayWordAudio(Word word, AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer player)
    {
        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".wav";

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(word.Audio);

        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(fileStream);
        }

        player.URL = tempFile;

        File.Delete(tempFile);
    }
```

Can someone please suggest a solution to this problem? Maybe I shouldn't delete the file at the end of the method? But then temp files would pile up...

I am on Windows 7...

Comment: You'll have to post some of the code you're using in order for us to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I solved the problem... it was in fact the deletion of file that caused this...

solution:

```
public static void PlayWordAudio(Word word, AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer player)
    {
        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".wav";

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(word.Audio);

        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(fileStream);
        }

        player.URL = tempFile;

        RunDelayed(5000, File.Delete, tempFile); //if we delete file immediately then clip sometimes would not be played
    }        

    public delegate void DelayedFuncion(string param);

    public static void RunDelayed(int delay, DelayedFuncion function, string param = null)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        DelayedArgs args = new DelayedArgs() { delayedFunction = function, param = param };
        timer.Tag = args;
        timer.Tick += TimerElapsed;            
        timer.Interval = delay;

        timer.Start();
    }

    private static void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = sender as System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
        timer.Stop();
        DelayedArgs args = timer.Tag as DelayedArgs;
        args.delayedFunction(args.param);
    }


    class DelayedArgs
{
    public Util.DelayedFuncion delayedFunction;
    public string param;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the file is being deleted quicker than it can get played.

Can you try this in stead of `File.Delete(tempFile);` utilizing the [PlayStateChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event

```
player.PlayStateChange += (snd, psce) => {
     switch (psce.newState)
    {
        case 1:    // Stopped (maybe use 12 =>  Last )
            File.Delete(tempFile);
            break;
        default:
            Debug.WriteLine(psce.newState);
            break;
    }
};
```

You might have to unsubscribe the event if you keep the player object around a long time.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get this: Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\David\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp5F17.tmp.wav' is denied. on the File.Delete line... not sure why.. maybe the file is still played and thus not released. If I use 12 instead of 1 the files don't get deleted... my solution below works so I'll just use that. Thanx anyway - I didn't think of that possibility -- maybe it would be possible to make it work..